# How to click on youtube video homepage in Python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

i tried this code but it is not working please help

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
sleep(5)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com")
sleep(10)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='video-title'][contains(@href,'v=38IEolI8f-w')]").click()
sleep(15)           
sleep(3)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Could you include any error tracebacks your code gives you?

Answer (score 0):

Probably your xpath isn't correct.
I think because it is an Id you can use only that:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='video-title']").click()
```

If you provide screenshot of the element attribute, I'll be more confident about it.

By the way get rid of those sleeps in your code, it make it looks a bit bad.

Comment: take any video of random youtube homepage and give me code how to click that video thanks in advance

Comment: I think it should work: `driver.findElement(By.TagName("ytd-thumbnail"))[1].click()`